# How to register a widget when saving a post?

Tags: widgets, hooks, save-post

I've tried to solve my problem in the simplest way, but it doesn't work: why?

```
  function createNewWidgetSavingAPost($post_id) {


        add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){

            $new_widget = new myWdgetClass("widget_id");

            register_widget( $new_widget );

          });

   }

 add_action('save_post', 'createNewWidgetSavingAPost', 10);
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to only register a widget when a post is saved. Widgets need to be registered on every page load. Are you trying to add a specific instance of a widget to a sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [hook order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), `widget_init` is a hook that is quite early in the page execution order. So, by the time `save_post` is fired `widget_init` has already passed. If you add an action to a hook that has already passed, nothing will happen.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what you are trying to do, we can advise a suitable solution?  There are ways to list posts in widgets. Do you really want a widget for every new post ?   It's not impossible (you could update an option each time a post is saved, then have code early on look up the options and create a widget for each post)  BUT may not be the best way to address what you are trying to achieve? Also It would never show anywhere unless it got added to a sidebar.

Comment: Sure. I Would like create a widget when a new post (custom post type: "widget") is created. To make this, I thought to create the widget when saving, with the idea of adding later a line of code like "if (!thiswidget) { createAWidget() }"...

Comment: As explained it is pointless to create a widget when a new post is created, because soon afterwards the page refreshes and the widget is gone. You probably mean something else, but it is unclear what.